# Disable terminal logs for firebase serve command

Tags: windows, firebase, visual-studio-code, firebase-cli

Whenever I run `firebase serve` and loads the firebase site locally, my VSCode terminal fills with lengthy and unnecessary logs like this.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2019:21:10:23 +0000] "GET /security HTTP/1.1" 200 10208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2019:21:10:24 +0000] "GET /assets/css/Features-Boxed.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1075 "http://localhost:5000/security" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2019:21:10:24 +0000] "GET /assets/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 12392 "http://localhost:5000/security" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2019:21:10:24 +0000] "GET /__/firebase/init.js HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://localhost:5000/security" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2019:21:10:24 +0000] "GET /assets/img/svg/home_white.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 1305 "http://localhost:5000/security" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2019:21:10:24 +0000] "GET /__/firebase/7.5.0/firebase-app.js HTTP/1.1" 200 12066 "http://localhost:5000/security" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2019:21:10:25 +0000] "GET /__/firebase/7.5.0/firebase-analytics.js HTTP/1.1" 200 21623 "http://localhost:5000/security" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2019:21:10:25 +0000] "GET /__/firebase/7.5.0/firebase-auth.js HTTP/1.1" 200 163643 "http://localhost:5000/security" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2019:21:10:25 +0000] "GET /assets/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 5794 "http://localhost:5000/security" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 
NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2019:21:10:25 +0000] "GET /__/firebase/7.5.0/firebase-app.js.map HTTP/1.1" 200 70975 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2019:21:10:25 +0000] "GET /__/firebase/7.5.0/firebase-analytics.js.map HTTP/1.1" 200 113064 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2019:21:10:25 +0000] "GET /assets/css/style.css.map HTTP/1.1" 200 32580 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
```

I usually put some console.log statements here and that get lost in all this mess. How to disable it?

Terminal: VSCode built-in Terminal
Project: Firebase web app
Platform: Windows

Comment: File a feature request with the Firebase CLI GitHub: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: created feature request at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1839

Comment: I feel your pain.  As a workaround, I have a function `visibleConsoleLog(stuffYouWantToLog)` that adds '*********************' and a timestamp to the my `console.log`s, so that it pops out from the `serve` logs.  Not ideal, but at least helps find your own logs at a glance!